# How to print the current background value to the console?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am using a random value in the background function. How to print the current background value to the console?

```
let bcgrnd = [0,254];

function draw() {
    background(random(bcgrnd));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the random value in a variable:

```js
function draw() {
    var bc = random(bcgrnd);
    console.log(bc);
    background(bc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably would do it like @Rabbid76 suggested, but it also could be done like this:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(random(255),random(255),random(255));
  console.log(get(0,0));
  
}
```